# assign IF(AND formula to the cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to assign the formula I have to the cell using VBA. The code is like below :

```
x.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Formula = "=IF(AND(B2>TIME(9;0;0);B2<TIME(18;0;0);ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CIXIS";C2)));"TRUE";"FALSE")"
```

But interestingly the macros does not accept any if formula. I think it is because of the quotation mark but I used `Char(34)`, but no success. I even added double quotation mark, still not any success. I know that we should be able to assign formula using macros, what I am doing wrong? Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: Formulas assigned in VBA should use the US separator (comma, not semicolon)  Use `FormulaLocal` if you want to use `;`

Comment: Every time You use quotation mark in formula use it twice

Comment: Every time where quotation mark I added one more but no success. 

Changed all semicolon into comma still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Formula = _
         "=IF(AND(B2>TIME(9,0,0),B2<TIME(18,0,0)," & _
         "ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""CIXIS"",C2))),""TRUE"",""FALSE"")"
```

Comment: It worked. But can you please explain me what was `& _` for ?

Comment: ahh okay :) so we can use without that as well? Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Small note, the formula would return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, OP might aswell leave out the returning values `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` @AliMammadov